# Get anchor tag text using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I don't know if it is possible! Maybe my thought is also wrong.  I want to invoke a search corresponding to all links in my Wordpress blog.

I am using an Ajax call for my other search in this site.  How can I retrieve a linking text from hypertext tag in html.
eg: `<a href='www.example.com'>demo</a>`.here i want to get '**demo**' as input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var links_html_list = [];

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var l in links) {
   if(typeof links[i] == undefined) continue;
   links_html_list.push(links[i].innerHTML);
}

function search(term) {
   var results = [];
   for(var l in links_html_list) {
       var cur = links_html_list[l];
       if(typeof cur == undefined) continue; 
       if(cur.indexOf(term) != -1) results.push(cur);
   }
   return (results.length > 0) ? results : null;
}
```

What the `search` function does is it loops through the list of strings and if any have the `term` in it (`indexOf`), then it will get pushed into an array which is then returned. If there are no matches, it will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$homePageText = file_get_contents(file.html);
preg_match_all('/<a .*?>(.*?)<\/a>/',$homePageText,$matches);
```

Then all anchor text elements will be stored in the array $matches.

Comment: Thank for your replay.But,this method not help me...which is getting an error like Unknown modifier 'a'

Comment: Sorry, add a backslash before the "/a" I've edited my posted code.